# Analytics imported conversions show as "No recent conversions"

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads

I have imported a few goals from Analytics into Google Ads, but they show as "No recent conversions":

[image]

The reason it's confusing me is that there are quite a few conversions in Analytics.

I believe I've linked the account correctly:

[image]

Sorry for the dumbness of the question, I'm figuring things out here.

Comment: Are you sure the conversions in Analytics are attributed to google / cpc?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins how can I make sure of it?

Comment: Go into Analytics, look at a time period where you have a definite goal completion that you're tracking as a conversion, then add source/medium as a secondary dimension.